# How to redirect to another view from button click (ExtJS 6.2)

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have this button class defined as follows :

```
Ext.define('Mine.view.buttons', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.MyClass',
    requires: [
            'Mine.view.Main',
            'Mine.view.newDashboard'
        ],
    xtype: 'myclass',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        html: '<img src=\"../../iDeviceMap.png\" width="76" height="76"/>',
        text: '',
        width: 76,
        height: 76,
        handler: function() {

this.redirectTo('main', true);

    }]
});
```

Which i embed in a Panel view along with other components (composing the main view) defined in another class.
My problem is that `this.redirectTo('main', true);` doesn't work. How to do the redirection with the right "this" that of the main view where the button is defined (say Mine.view.Main) ?
Q2 : how to call the parent view (Mine.view.Main) from the handler of the button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button handler should be a function in the controller.  The method in the controller with then call the redirectTo method.

Or you could get the panel's controller in the button's handler and call it from there.... best to do it in the controller so if you write a different view for a phone or tablet each view can share the controller.

[A fiddle showing switching panels](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/39oc&view/editor)

[Same fiddle so you can see the hash change](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/39oc/preview)

EDIT: @ltes - I wrote a fiddle that did what you wanted it to do.  You ask a question about two methods. It would be much faster for you to simple review the documentation on each of these methods.

[Ext.create method](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/modern/Ext.html#method-create)
[Ext.Container down method](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/modern/Ext.Container.html#method-down)

You don't understand the tool kit you are using.  Ext.Create will create a new object  this.getView().down and up() look in the hierarchy to find a component. If you want to replace a panel then use the remove() and add() method on the panel. YOu don't have to execute Ext.create when you add you can simply pass a config:

```
panel.add({
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'This is my new panel',
    html: 'new panel data'
}
```

Comment: Alright thanks, in the handler instead of doing `this.getView()` like you do i create the view using `Ext.create('widget.main');` is it correct to do it ? Also i want to switch to the view when i set the URL adding `#main` for that i add the route to the view but it's not working what could be the problem ?

Comment: Also when i use the back button of the navigator the URL updates but doesn't reload page nor update the view.

Comment: the second fiddle listed in my answer, the back button and the previous button work as expected.

Comment: i still doesn't get how routing in ExtJS works : is the view automatically displayed when there's a route match or do you have to create the view in the handler ?

Comment: You have to create the view and display it in the handler.  It is just firing an event and calling a handler.   As you can see in the fiddle I created, when the route is panelone the function onPanelOne is called.  onPanelOne sets the active item to panel one via the setActiveItem on the tab panel.  So yes you have to do the work all the routing is doing is modifying the hashtag and handling the history.

Comment: Ok and can `Ext.Create` replace `this.GetView().Down() / .Up()` to display the views ?

Comment: Also the problem is that you are only displaying panels within another fixed panel, i am totally changing the window on click.

Comment: Sir, I respectfully request that you read the sencha documentation.  It is very good and explains how ExtJS works.  The questions you are asking have nothing to do with redirecting.  Also the ExtJS examples show how to do lots of stuff.  There is also a tutorial.  the up and down functions are finding components in the current hierarchy.  ExtJS is a great framework if you know how to use it.  Going over the documentation is a great place to start.  Click on docs on the main sencha website.

Comment: I got it working out, but only if click a button and change the view i am able to go back to the original view (but from there if i want to get forward and return to the second view then it doesn't work ). It's like the history of my navigation is not taking care of by ExtJS.

Comment: it's probably becausee i'm creating the view classes on click events and not playing up down with the view hierachies like you did in your fiddle.

Comment: Yes and thanks a lot for your posts, examples & comments and your help.